# MikTeX updates fail right after install

Tags: miktex, installing, winedt

I read several posts with similar issues but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I had MiKTeX 2.9 installed on my Windows 10 machine for many years and one fine day it just stopped working in my editor (WinEdt). I went for the draconian path and uninstalled MikTeX only to find that reinstalling it didn't work out that well.

I tried both 2.9 as well as the latest 21.2 packages. Installation itself seem alright but I always get this error message at the end of the updates:

### *The executed process did not succeed.
fileName="C:\Users\EB\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-fc-cache.exe", exitCode="1"*

I have disabled my AVG and all Adobe tasks prior to installation, in case those programs are working against me. Also, I ran the installer file as admin, selected admin only installation, picked a path with a folder MiKTeX 2.9, and selected "ask me first" for packages on the fly. These are common solutions to installation errors that I saw from other posts.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: try to find out, why fc-cache fails. Call e.g. `fc-cache -v` on a command line. Perhaps you get a message ...

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. I ran that on cmd (admin) and got these error messages: "The code execution cannot proceed because MiKTEX210200-fontconfig.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."
"The code execution cannot proceed because MiKTEX210200-core.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."
"The code execution cannot proceed because MiKTEX210200-app.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."
"The code execution cannot proceed because MiKTEX210200-getopt.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

Comment: By the way, these were the same messages I got on WinEdt during compilation which led me to take on this path of reinstalling MiKTeX in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: the numbers in the dll look wrong. I have there 210300. Try `initexmf --mklinks --verbose --force` (perhaps also with `--admin`, don't know.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. Funny enough, I was able to run that command but compiling in WinEdt then hung (though this time without error messages). In my last-ditch attempt to reinstall MikTeX, I tried using the net installer rather than the basic installer, and now things are working again! I have no idea why.

Comment: well perhaps the basic installer is broken. You should report the issue (assuming that you used the newest version available).

Comment: Has this problem been fixed already? I'm getting the same.